# Distributed lock with TTL

Tags: locking, distributed-system

When we have a distributed lock with TTL, it is possible that lock will expire because of TTL config and the process which had that lock has not finished computation and it will continue to manipulate the object for which it acquired lock as it doesn't know that lock has already expired. How can we avoid that scenario?

Comment: I can only think of rising the TTL or creating a fallback mechanism for the lock release when a `TTL is expired` error is returned. Also TTL must be set according to the process duration.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you are looking for is called "fencing token". Long story short - every mutation command/operation should include the token and the executor should check if the token is still valid.

The token is just a number, call it "term", every time a new lock is issued, the term get increased.

The executor has a simple logic, it never accepts commands with an old term.

Arguably, this is the only option to truly avoid any lock related issues. Stuff like having timestamps, or explicit lock releases - all of them are inherently prone to various race issues.

Another pointer I recommend to look at - Red Lock algorithm; and the issues it has - more on this here: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I know about fencing token, but my question is different.

Comment: "it will continue to manipulate the object for which it acquired lock as it doesn't know that lock has already expired" - maybe I misunderstand, but fencing token is the solution here. All other options, like checking a linearizable storage, they all suffer from the same issue with stop-the-world. In fact, any option with pattern "IF check something THEN do" is inherently broken. Maybe you could clarify why fencing token is not the solution here?

Comment: Because fencing token cannot stop 2 processes from accessing a resource at the same time.

Comment: you have two different processes and the rendezvous point is the resource. You actually have to have a fencing token to make the decision in that rendezvous point. This, of course, implies that the resource or resource proxy understands the fencing token. And this is a fundamental property of distributed process that your worker processes can't make local decisions if they do or don't have the lock.

Comment: If you don't control the resource (or can't have a proxy), another option is to use consensus based decisions b/n worker threads. This is much more complicated to implement correctly and you have to take into consideration CAP theorem - since you want CP (consistent + partitioned) and sacrifice Availability. That may work for you. You will have to be creating with STONITH. Also, you could get some ideas from https://patents.google.com/patent/US6708175